# Make viewport stick to bottom of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to fix the viewport to the the bottom of the page, so when the page loads, the user first sees the bottom of the page rather than the top.

This is for a messaging screen, so the user needs to be fixed to the latest messages, at the bottom of the page as opposed to the older ones at the top.

Comment: Please provide relevant code (HTML/CSS/JS) so we could help you better. As for my suggestion, I think you can run this JS on page load: window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this using jQuery by following code

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
});
```

and using only javascript you can use

```
 window.onload = function(e) {
                window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="index.html#bottom">Home</a>
```

**bottom** is **id** of tag at the bottom of your page you want to focus on

Comment: he wants to fix the viewport to the the bottom of the page when page loads, not on click.

Comment: still correct if the user loads the page using the anchor #bottom